# Django: TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '|' from 'eligibility_date|'

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I am using below code in one of my templates. and getting the error `TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '|' from 'eligibility_date|'.` I have searched a lot and could not find any usage of `date` filter with `{% with %} {% endwith %}`.
`

```
{% with eligibility_date=eligibility_date|date: "m/d/Y" %}
    {% blocktrans %} {{eligibility_date}} {% endblocktrans %}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be space between `date` and `"m/d/Y"`:

```
{% with eligibility_date=eligibility_date|date:"m/d/Y" %}
```